# Can I delete "Reserved by the System" partition, created by failed hibernation?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, hibernate

My notebook enters into hibernation when the battery gets too low, however, I had left an old phone charging in the USB port, that happens to freeze the bootup of the notebook, and when it hibernated, it froze, and removing the phone from the USB did nothing.

I had to fix the bootup with a windows installation disk, but when I got the computer working again, it had a 350mb partition named "Reserved by the System", and these are the contents of the partition:

[image: Files in this partition]

I lost what was open at the time, but I had nothing important that wasn't saved in my HDD. So, can I use diskpart to delete that partition showing in my file browser and add it's space to another partition?

It's a notebook and I use Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete it, although I cannot foresee any issues that would arise from you deleting this.

You would need to use the Disk Management tool (Control Panel > Administrative tools > Create and format hard disk partitions / Disk Management).

Right click on the offending partition, and delete it. Then expand another partition to cover the new empty space.

Due to a restriction on the Disk Management software, you cannot expand any partitions to the left, only to the right. So if the `reserved by system` partition is all the way to the left, then you might as well leave it. Otherwise, you'd need either a 3rd party tool to do it (Linux live CD with Gparted, or another Windows program). Do note that if you try to expand the booted partition, Windows may prevent it.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, it's all the way to the left, leading me to believe it's actually part of the system, as there is no other partition for that purpose.  
So it probably wouldn't boot if I deleted it. :c
But anyway, at least now I know better what not to do with it. xD

Comment: I'd give it 95% chance of rebooting if you deleted it. But since you can't use that space w/out installing a third party utility to expand the root partition, I personally would not remove it because of the risk of utilizing the free space after removal. But the removal itself is unlikely to cause harm. If I needed the extra space, I would upgrade the drive already in there